# How do I create a new Beamer environment with a verbatim environment?

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm creating a Beamer presentation that has a lot of example LaTeX in it, which has to go in a verbatim environment.  I'm getting tired of typing

```
\begin{example}
  \begin{verbatim}
  Verbatim Text
  \end{verbatim}
\end{example}
```

I wish to create a new command or environment that will shorthand this for me.  I also need this for blocks and theorems, since I'm using those frequently as well.  But if I can figure it out for examples, it should be easy to translate to another example.

I can't create a new environment or command using just \begin{verbatim}, since it cuts off the rest of the command.  So I switched to using the fancyvrb package, and tried the following:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}{}

\newcommand{\makeexample}[1]{
    \begin{example}
        \begin{MyVerbatim}
        #1

        \end{MyVerbatim}
    \end{example}
}

\makeenvironment{VerbExample}{\begin{example}
    \begin{MyVerbatim}}{\end{MyVerbatim}\end{example}}
```

That gives me the \makeexample{Example Text} command, and the \begin{VerbExample}...\end{VerbExample} environment, but they both still throw errors on compile.  The frame I'm trying to use them in looks like this (I've got the [fragile] option on the frame, so it's not that).

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Why Doesn't Verbatim Work?}

    \makeexample{Verbatim Text}

    \begin{VerbExample}
        Verbatim Text
    \end{VerbExample}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{VerbExample}
{\example\semiverbatim}
{\endsemiverbatim\endexample}
```

Frame definition:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{VerbExample}
test test test $t$ $\\omega$
test test
\end{VerbExample}
\end{frame}
```

Verbatim cannot go inside `\newcommand`. Semiverbatim is defined by Beamer and works well with it. The three characters `\` `{` `}` must be escaped as `\\` `\{` `\}`.

Source: Beamer user guide, pp. 119-120
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but since I'm putting a lot of LaTeX code in the these "Verbatim Examples", having to escape all the \, {, and } characters will be more hassle than just typeing \begin{example}\begin{verbatim}...

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, verbatim and beamer tend not to play nice. Creative solutions usually don't exist. The best solution is probably to add shortcuts to your text editor, e.g., via tab completion.