# Latex's verbatim: how to indent every instance?

Tags: latex

I have a latex document with a bunch of verbatim text. I would like to indent every single instance of these.

For example:

```
This is regular text.
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text.
\end{verbatim}
```

I want "This is verbatim text" to be indented a centimeter or two. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap all your `verbatim` environments in `quote` environments:

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
This is indented verbatim text.
Works for multiple lines, too.
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
```

Comment: This has the undesirable side effect of adding an extra vertical skip above the verbatim text.

Answer (score 7):

This extends ezod's answer above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{qv}
{\quote\Verbatim}
{\endVerbatim\endquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{qv}
This text
is indented.
\end{qv}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Another way is to simply add the `xleftmargin` option to `RecustomVerbatimEnvironment` before `\begin{document}`:

```
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=5mm}
```

Comment: Should be ...
\newenvironment{qv}
{\quote\Verbatim}
{\endVerbatim\endquote}
...  ie. there's mistake in the third argument to \newenvironment

Comment: You are correct. I edited. Strangely, the original version did compile and produced the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Any indent

```
\catcode`\@=11
\let \saveverbatime \@xverbatim
\def \@xverbatim {\leftskip = 1cm\relax\saveverbatime}
\catcode`\@=12
```

Comment: I would like to modify also the upper and lower spaces around the verbatim. `\topskip` and `\footskip` do not work, adding `\vspace` increases the head space. Do you know a solution for the bottom spacing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer based on redefining \@xverbatim is the right approach. Unfortunately, this only works for the standard verbatim environment, and lots of people these days use the verbatim style which is much better. (If you don't, start doing it!)

For that one, here is the winning trick:

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@startline{\verbatim@line{\leavevmode\kern20pt\relax}}
\makeatother

Put that in your preamble, and every verbatim environment, as well every \verbatiminput file will nicely be indented.

Sheesh people, this took me 30 seconds of reading the source....

Victor.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new command that indents how you like.

Something like this:

```
\newcommand{\myverb}[1]{ \indent{ \begin{verbatim} #1 \end{verbatim} } }
```

This should let you do:

```
\myverb{ This is verbatim text. }
```

Comment: No way just to set something in the header of the document?

Comment: @cvondrick I don't think so, but you could define your own class. That's much harder than what Brian is suggesting though.

Comment: agreed. I'll accept this answer unless a better one comes along shortly. Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to make this work? LaTeX doesn't seem to like `\end{verbatim}` inside a `\newcommand` definition. As posted here, I get a compilation error.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe this solution works. Verbatim cannot go inside newcommand. See my answer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121035/how-do-i-create-a-new-beamer-environment-with-a-verbatim-environment/2126150#2126150

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this because you are formatting a lot of program code.  If so, consider the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.